# View log files on rooted Nexus 9

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, root-access, 5.0-lollipop, logging

I'd like to check some log files of a app I've downloaded from the browser.
I rooted my device already and saw in the "SuperSU"-App a Logs-Tab. How can/do I use that? Or do I have to do something more?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the app called CatLog - LogCAt reader it can read all your logs and it's open source

Comment: This answer might be helpful if you add a link to the app you're recommending.

Comment: True, but I found it easy on the PlayStore

Comment: Yeah it's on playstore and it's easy to find on playstore i don't have the time to search for the link myself if someone can edit and add it i will accept also i forgot to say that the logs you see on SuperSu is the logs from apps that required root access only not other logs